# Micro ATX Motherboard on OEM case

Tags: motherboard, screws, micro-atx

My motherboard (micro atx) lines up with these holes in a case I found. (pic related)

[image: - - Picture Link - -]

The black circles are pre-installed in the case (I can't remove those standoffs) and the motherboard lines up on them.
The red circles are those holes (4 in total) that the motherboard also lines up, but there is nothing there for the screws to go in. So, I was wondering, what do I put in there? Are there any special standoff screws for these holes?

Comment: those are probably for oem clip/standoffs. they are probably currently attached to the oem motherboard. Do you still have the old motherboard? Otherwise, perhaps this random image from google: ( http://www.pccables.com/images/03002.jpg )

Comment: TBH, unless there is a really good reason to stay with the case I would just move to something more "standard"... Newegg, Amazon, and other vendors all carry MicroATX cases for under $30 with shipping, putting you into a more standardized case. I have seen local shops like MicroCenter with cases on sale for under $20. Then your compatibility and fit issues should drop to near zero now and in the foreseeable future.

Comment: Yes I will upgrade the case shortly, but right now this is all I have! Unfortunately, the oem motherboard is gone. Thanks for the reply acejavelin!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need the adjustable stand-offs that would have originally come with the chassis (and may still be stuck to the motherboard last installed in it).

The odds are they were plastic slide-in ones that have snap-downs to lock the board to it.

Similar to these:

[image]

If you did not get them with the chassis/system when you purchased it, and you can't find proper ones [via Amazon](http://www.amazon.ca/dp/B00032Q1OO) or alike (check the existing hard-mounted stand-offs' height), then contact the place of purchase, or the chassis manufacturer directly, to try and obtain some.